# How to compute correlation of 2 matrices but using specific idx for each row

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, correlation

I want to compute correlation of 2 matrices by each row choosing specific idx but without using loop.

For example:

```
A = np.array([[ 4,  8,  9,  2, 10,  3,  7,  2,  3,  4],
              [ 2,  4,  4,  8,  4,  4,  6,  4,  6,  5],
              [10,  7,  3,  2,  4,  2,  5,  2,  7, 10]])

B = np.array([[ 4, 10,  6,  7,  2,  9,  2, 10,  6,  1],
              [ 3, 10, 10,  6,  8,  6,  4,  6,  2,  1],
              [ 3,  3,  1,  6,  7,  1, 10,  8,  1,  6]])
```

for 1st row idx = [1,5,6,8,9], for 2nd it and 3rd row idx are different and numer of idx is different (e.g. idx = [1, 2, 6])

So first result is np.corrcoef(A[0, idx], B[0, idx]).

How can do it for all rows but using only numpy?

My code is below

```
threshold = np.arange(80, 161, 5)
sample_math = np.random.normal(60, 10, size=(len(threshold), 10**4))
sample_rus = np.random.normal(60, 10, size=(len(threshold), 10**4))
sample = sample_rus + sample_math

idx_row, idx_col = np.where(sample > threshold[:, None])
np.corrcoef(sample_math[idx_row, idx_col], sample_rus[idx_row, idx_col])
```

Here the problem is that variable sample_math[idx_row, idx_col] and sample_rus[idx_row, idx_col] has shape (*some number*,) so python just calculate corr for all rows at once

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop to calculate the correlation separately for each row, something like:

```
    ...
    idx = [[1,5,6,8,9], [1, 2, 6], [0, 3, 7]]
    
    correlations = []
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        corr = np.corrcoef(A[i, idx[i]], B[i, idx[i]])[0, 1]
        correlations.append(corr)
    
    correlations = np.array(correlations)
```

I hope that's helpful.

Cheers :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! You are right but i wanted to know is there a way to do that without using loop but only numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative.  You can use numpy function np.take_along_axis() to extract the elements from your A and B matrices corresponding to the indices in idx.

You could write something like:

```
...
idx = [[1,5,6,8,9], [1, 2, 6], [0, 3, 7]]

# Extract the values from A and B using idx
A_values = np.take_along_axis(A, np.array(idx), axis=1)
B_values = np.take_along_axis(B, np.array(idx), axis=1)

correlations = np.corrcoef(A_values, B_values, rowvar=False)
correlations = correlations.diagonal(offset=A.shape[0])
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for answer! I tried your code and got an error `IndexError: indices' must be an integer array.` The problem is that `idx = array([list([1, 5, 6, 8, 9]), list([1, 2, 6]), list([0, 3, 7])]` so it won't fit as index